# Add To Tuples Within a List With Filter

Tags: haskell

```
Authors = [(String, Int)]
File Filename DateTime Authors
```

Example:

```
File "DSC023.jpg" "01/05/2012 22:40" [("Test1",1),("Test2",2)]
```

How would I search for DSC023.jpg and add another author to the list?

```
findFile n = find (\(File x _ _ _) -> x == n) fileDatabase
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a few functions:

```
addAuthor author File x y as = File x y (author:as)

fileName File n _ _ _ = n

findFile name = find (\x -> (fileName x) == name)
```

This should give you everything to build the function you need.

Comment: How would I work this into a list [File] I am having a few issues.

Comment: @user1368696 How about showing code that has the issues? No one here is going to write your program for you (given an incomplete spec) or has a crystalball.

Comment: findFile:: String -> File
findFile n = find (\x -> x == n) fileDatabase - Couldn't match expected type `File' with actual type `Maybe a0'

Comment: @user1368696 Please don't add you code in comments, edit the question. In your case the explicit type you specify is wrong. Look at the type of `find`.

Comment: Maybe a I've seen the type, I am working with what I understand, I do not work with functional programming languages, I understand what I need to do in Java / C# / C / C++ / PHP but not Haskell.

Comment: @user1368696 Also in Java and all other languages with static typing the type returned from a function needs to match. You should read a turorial otherwise this is going to be very painful.

Comment: I've added my solution to get a ping back on the element found in my original post, I need it to be in the format of File but I get: Just .........

Comment: @user1368696: You should read up on the Maybe type and pattern matching in whatever textbook or tutorial you're using.